# as3 - How can you combine variables into one variable?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have multiple variables that have the same effect and don't need to be written 5 times over again.

How can I combine all these variables into one?

Let's say I have block0, block1, block3

I want them all to the same thing when it should so that way I don't need to write it multiple times?

For example:

```
if hittest wall
{
 block0.x -= 5;
 block1.x -= 5;
 block2.x -= 5;
}
```

What I would like:

```
if hittest wall
{
 blocksack.x -= 5;
}
```

Comment: Not enough information to answer. It depends what those variable refer to, what they are meant to handle, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these are all `DisplayObject`s.

To group `DisplayObject`s, add them to a `DisplayObjectContainer`:

```
var blockContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
blockContainer.addChild(block0);
blockContainer.addChild(block1);
blockContainer.addChild(block2);
addChild(blockContainer);
```

Now you can move them all by moving the container:

```
blockContainer.x -= 5;
```

---

There's another problem with your code. It looks like you use variable names with numbers at the end to distinguish them. That's a bad practice.

- It's tedious to give dozens of objects individual names if you never
  want to interact with them individually.
- It's also prone to error and inflexible. If you want to add more blocks,
  what was the last number you used so you don't use a number twice?
  What if you want to remove the first 3 blocks of 20, will you rename
  the rest to start at 0?

**Having all these variables is your actual problem.**

They should be grouped from the beginning. As you are apparently placing the blocks by hand, a simple solution to this is again the use of a container.

Place all blocks in an empty container without giving them instance names.
Then use the methods of that `DisplayObjectContainer`, namely `numChildren` and `getChildAt()` to put all of its children into an array. You can then iterate over the array to apply some action to all its elements if you want, but again, for changing the `.x` property it should be sufficient to simply move the container.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with my comment, you deleting it is pure censorship. Are you against freedom of expression?

Comment: @BotMaster I cannot delete comments.

Comment: whoever did has no understanding of this question and just like to censor.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate function than will do the movement for every object. Eg

```
private function moveAllBlocks(dist:Number):void {
  block0.x -= dist;
  block1.x -= dist;
  block2.x -= dist;
}
```

Then you can just call the function from wherever you want by calling

```
moveAllBlocks(5);
```